# What is the collective noun for words?

Tags: synonyms, collective-nouns

What is the collective noun for words, like say "a group of words."
Is there a more specific collective noun and if there is, what is it?
Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: What sort of 'group'? A sentence or phrase is made up of words which have been put together to convey a meaning; if they are random words it's just a 'list' of words.

Answer (score 3):

It really depends on the context where you are using the word you are finding. "Phrase" usually refers to a group of words which has meaning to it.

For example, "she had some amazing news to share but nobody to share it with."
"some amazing news" is a phrase, while "she to with to" is not. The latter something is a phrase just because it has multiple words.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike, say, cows.  Word don't form herds!

Words can be structured into phrases, clauses, sentences and so on.

"a big red book" is a phrase "The cat sat on the mat" is a clause and a sentence

You can create a list of words.  "red blue green orange pink" is a list of colour words.